# SQLAlchemy: NotImplementedError when joining with subquery

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy

I'm trying to join a query object with a subquery. I have verified that the two queries work independently.

This is the code:

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker
from sqlalchemy import text

from project import models

SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URL = "XXX"

engine = create_engine(SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URL)
SessionDB = sessionmaker(autocommit=False, autoflush=False, bind=engine)

Base = declarative_base()

session = SessionDB()
query = (
    session.query(
        models.Homes,
        models.RentalData,
        models.Descriptions,
    )
    .filter(
        models.Homes.id == models.RentalData.home_id,
    )
    .filter(
        models.Homes.id == models.Descriptions.home_id,
    )
)

query_2 = (
    session.query(models.Homes)
    .from_statement(
        text(
            """
    SELECT 
        id,
        (SELECT 
            ARRAY(
                    SELECT image_url 
                    FROM listings.images 
                    WHERE listings.images.home_id = listings.homes.id))
            AS image_url 
    FROM listings.homes"""
        )
    )
    .subquery()
)


query = query.join(query_2, models.Homes.id == query_2.c.id)
```

The traceback looks like this:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/user/app/merge_example.py", line 52, in <module>
    query = query.join(query_2, models.Listings.id == query_2.c.id)
                                                      ^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/user/app/env/lib/python3.11/site-packages/sqlalchemy/util/langhelpers.py", line 1113, in __get__
    obj.__dict__[self.__name__] = result = self.fget(obj)
                                           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/user/app/env/lib/python3.11/site-packages/sqlalchemy/sql/selectable.py", line 737, in columns
    self._populate_column_collection()
  File "/home/user/app/env/lib/python3.11/site-packages/sqlalchemy/sql/selectable.py", line 1643, in _populate_column_collection
    self.element._generate_fromclause_column_proxies(self)
  File "/home/user/app/env/lib/python3.11/site-packages/sqlalchemy/sql/selectable.py", line 3044, in _generate_fromclause_column_proxies
    raise NotImplementedError()
NotImplementedError
```

Why does this join not work? I'm using Postgres 11, Python 3.11, SQLAlchemy 1.4.

Answer (score 1):

You need to specify which columns are available, like this:

```
from sqlalchemy.dialects.postgresql import ARRAY

with Session(engine) as session, session.begin():
    #...
    sql = text("""SELECT 
        id,
        (SELECT 
            ARRAY(
                    SELECT image_url 
                    FROM listings.images 
                    WHERE listings.images.home_id = listings.homes.id))
            AS image_url 
    FROM listings.homes""")
    sql = sql.columns(models.Homes.id, column("image_url", ARRAY(String)))
    sql_subq = sql.subqery()
    # now sql_subq.c.id is availabile, as is sql_subq.c.image_url
```

The example here loads an entire orm object from a subquery but talks about using `columns()` and how the selectable it returns has more features:

https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/orm/queryguide.html#getting-orm-results-from-textual-and-core-statements